# Message logging, incorrect parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to have an automated logging system that put all send and deleted messages but every once in awhile I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\Bots\DS BOT\cog\logger.py", line 25, in on_message
    print(f"User: {c.author} said --- {c.content} --- in #{c.channel}");
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

It completely ruins the entire process and loops the error, it is very annoying to restart the program every time I run into this

I put the command in a cog btw

Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands


# https://youtu.be/BoVOzm1uhUA
class logger(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, c):
        if(c.guild):
            if c.guild.name == "Sniper's lounge":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
            elif c.guild.name == "New GAR":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");          
                    pass;
        else:
            pass;

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, c):
        if(c.guild):
            if c.guild.name == "Sniper's lounge":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
            elif c.guild.name == "New GAR":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
        else:
            pass;


#print(f"{c.created_at} || Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(logger(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with discord.py, however, if you are simply trying to run it and you are fine with not getting all of them perfectly logged, just use this:

```
try:
    print(f"User: {c.author} said --- {c.content} --- in #{c.channel}");
except OSError:
    print('An error occurred')
```

Comment: Like so:https://imgur.com/a/vSTgWjj Because I am getting an error: "unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<unknown>, line 16)"

Comment: @DanA one of your print lines is mis-indented by 1 space

Comment: can you point to exactly where because I have looked it over and it seems everything is correctly indented